# Htaccess causing subdomain '404 not found' error

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, hosting

I'm trying to create a subdomain for showing clients their websites in development, by creating a 'subdomains' folder within 'public_html', and then creating individual 'subdomain' folders within that 'subdomains' folder, and redirecting each new site to its associated folder.

My problem is I expect with my htaccess code, whereb navigating to, for example, subdomain.website.com, I get the error below:

"The requested URL /.php was not found on this server."

...

Here's the code for my htaccess at the moment, just not sure how I can alter this to allow me to use this setup for each future subdomain in the 'subdomains' folder without getting this issue.

`ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

`# RewriteEngine On`
`# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]`
`# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm in way over my head with htaccess stuff. Thank you in advance!

*EDIT* just confirming that the only file in the subdomain folder at the moment is an index.php file

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule in top of your domain .htaccess file, %1 is your subdomain folder and $1 is your request (default document folder would be index.php).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Check manual entry of subdomain folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding the code ad switched 'example' to my domain name, but now getting an Internal Server Error.

Should the /%1/$1 take care of all subdomains? Or do I need to change %1 to 'subdomains', and $1 to the folder name of the subdomain within that folder that I'm trying to target?

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Hmm, check please second rule with manual entry subdomain folder and index.php for subdomain.example.com